# android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

### employee_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:backgroundSplit"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter class:

```
class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById( R.id.progressBar );
    }

}

class EmpViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView name , type;

    public EmpViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.fname);
        type = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.lname );
    }
}

public class MyAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int view_type_item = 0 , view_type_loading = 1;
    ILoadMore iLoadMore;
    boolean isLoading;
    Activity activity;
    List<Employee> employees;
    int visibleThreshold = 5;
    int lastVisibleItem , totalItemCount;


    public MyAdaptor(RecyclerView recyclerView , Activity activity, List<Employee> employees) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.employees = employees;

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener( new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled( recyclerView, dx, dy );
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if(!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
                {
                    if (iLoadMore != null)
                        iLoadMore.onLoadMore();
                    isLoading = true;
                }

            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return employees.get(position) == null ? view_type_loading:view_type_item;
    }

    public void setiLoadMore(ILoadMore iLoadMore) {
        this.iLoadMore = iLoadMore;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == view_type_item)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from( activity )
                    .inflate(R.layout.employee_layout , parent , false );
            return  new EmpViewHolder( view );
        }
        else if (viewType == view_type_loading){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from( activity )
                    .inflate( R.layout.employee_loading , parent, false );
            return new LoadingViewHolder( view );
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof EmpViewHolder)
        {
            Employee employee = employees.get(position);
            EmpViewHolder viewHolder = (EmpViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.name.setText( employees.get(position).getFname() );
            viewHolder.type.setText( employees.get( position ).getType() );
        }
        else if (holder instanceof  LoadingViewHolder)
        {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder)holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate( true );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return employees.size();
    }

    public void setLoaded(){
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

End of Adpoter.java

-------Stack Trace---------------------

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.foodorderingapp, PID: 22889
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                      com.example.user.foodorderingapp.EmployeeFiles.MyAdaptor.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdaptor.java:91)
```

Comment: So what's in `employee_layout.xml`? You can't just dump an error and expect us to fix it.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: It's so much easier to just paste your code in your question, both for you and for us. Paste it, highlight it and press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the entire stack trace as well? Same process for formatting.

Comment: @TheWanderer Done. Thanks a lot for going through the matter.

Comment: And just to confirm, Line 91 is the first inflator call?

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes it is . 
View view = LayoutInflater.from( activity )
                .inflate(R.layout.employee_layout , parent , false );
The above code extract to be exact

Comment: And you have the CardView library implemented in Gradle?

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes I do. version- 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:background="?android:backgroundSplit"` from your LinearLayout?

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks a lot it worked. Do you mind briefly explaining why that caused the app to terminate?

Comment: Sure hang on. I need to check out what that attribute is supposed to be...

Comment: Sure no fuss. Really appreciate your effort and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android.R.attr.backgroundSplit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#backgroundSplit) is for split ActionBars (showing extra buttons on the bottom of the layout, etc). It does define a background, but according to the docs, it could be referencing any type of resource, any type of theme, or even just a straight up hex color string.

LinearLayout's background field can only take a color, color reference or drawable reference.